# How should I watch and consider "batches" and "saved by batching" in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, profiler, batching

I am developing an android game and I have some lag under the "rendering" section of the profiler even if I have just a few objects (2k triangles) and simple shaders.

I was looking at the **batches** section of the Unity Stats and I saw that once I start and the level is generated there are about **250 batches** and the 95 % that number is **saved by batching** because most of my objects are static.

[image]

Online I saw that the total number of batches should be the one on the stats, in my case 27, + the number saved, in my case 256. So I thought that, even after the static batching, I had 271 batches which is too much for android.

That is when I tried to remove objects to see which one of them was creating so many batches, but every time I remove one of my static objects the **saved by batching** also decreases.

My question is: if I remove an object and it is decreasing also the **saved by batching** stat, does it mean that the object is batched well or it does not mean anything? I have actually still 271 batches or do I have to do 271 - 256 and so I have actually just 15 batches (which is perfect, but I still not understand my lag by the way).

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html to see if your lag actually comes from rendering you should checkout the Profiler

Comment: Not sure why you'd be getting lag when you're at 70fps

Comment: @AdamB I have lag when I run the game on android. The batches are the same but my fps drop to 15

Comment: @derHugo I do. I have 3 ms on scripts, 3 ms on physics, 3 ms on other, and 50 ms on rendering, and that causes the lag.